# Oracle ADF LOVs value binding to multiple text fileds

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, lov

I have a use case where I have created a view object that contains 3 values namely LOC_CODE, LOC_DESC, CITY_DESC. Now in my ADF form I would like to display all 3 values in such a way so that user would have a provision to select LOC_CODE From Popup(LOV) and rest two fileds LOC_DESC & CITY_DESC should be changed accordingly. Currently the popup shows all 3 values but when I select the row and click on OK button it only fills the LOC_CODE in 1 textbox.
Below is the scenario of the same:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Just need to add a textbox or drag and drop near respective field and bind it with required binding object. For e.g. in this case LOC_DESC & CITY_DESC is available in my data control  as DefLoc & DefCity that contains SQL to fetch respective description value. Now I need to drag and drop DefLoc & DefCity and binding is automatically done or just check binding in value.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add valuechangelistener to location code. set autosubmit true.

now in backing bean use following code:

```
    public void valuechangelistener(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    valueChangeEvent.getComponent().processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    BindingContext bctx = BindingContext.getCurrent();
    BindingContainer bindings = bctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    JUCtrlListBinding list = (JUCtrlListBinding)bindings.get("LOC_CODE");
    String selectedValue = (String)list.getAttributeValue();
    list.getListIterBinding().setCurrentRowWithKeyValue(selectedValue);
    Row currRow = list.getListIterBinding().getCurrentRow();

    if (currRow != null) {
        bndloc_desc.setValue(currRow.getAttribute("LOC_DESC"));
        bndcity_desc.setValue(currRow.getAttribute("CITY_DESC"));

    }
}
```

now set partial trigger to both location desc and city desc with id of LOC_CODE.
After doing this you will get your desired result.

update after implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case JDeveloper 12.2.1.3.0

```
    public void valueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {


    BindingContext bctx = BindingContext.getCurrent();
    BindingContainer bindings = bctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    JUCtrlListBinding list = (JUCtrlListBinding) bindings.get("YourBindingforLOV");

    String selectedValue = (String) valueChangeEvent.getNewValue();

    list.getListIterBinding().setCurrentRowWithKeyValue(selectedValue);
    Row currRow = list.getListIterBinding().getCurrentRow();

    if (currRow != null) {
        String s = (String) currRow.getAttribute("YourAttributeName");
    }
}
```